# Invalid Path Exception

Tags: swift, firebase, scroll, firebase-realtime-database

I am being able to scroll to the bottom of the collectionView but sometimes it throws an Invalid Path exception. I have tried checking numberOfSections and numberOfItemsInSection but the error still sometimes shows up and my app crashes. I also tried using setContentOffset method to scroll but the error still sometimes shows up.

This is the code that I am using to scroll to the bottom of the collectionView :

```
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid, let toId = user?.id else {
        return
    }


    let userMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid).child(toId)
    userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    guard let messageId = snapshot.key as? String else {
            return
        }

                let messagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                return
            }


            self.messages.append(Message(dictionary: dictionary))

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                //scroll to the last index

                   if self.messages.count > 0 {
                    if let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0) as? IndexPath? {
                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath!, at: .bottom, animated: false)
                }
                }
            })

            }, withCancel: nil)

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

I also tried this :

```
      DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                //scroll to the last index

                   if let _ = self.collectionView?.dataSource?.collectionView(self.collectionView!, cellForItemAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) {
                    if let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0) as? IndexPath? {
                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath!, at: .bottom, animated: false)
                }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to bottom of CollectionView without animation and without invalid path exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700716/scroll-to-bottom-of-collectionview-without-animation-and-without-invalid-path-ex)

Comment: Sorry that question was not answered and therefore I had to post this again ! I am deleting that question.

Comment: if you could share more details about the crash message error (prints, logs, etc.) it will be easier to guide you somewhere

Comment: @JavierMedina NSInvalidArgumentException
attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x1c0229e60> {length = 2, path = 0 - 22}

Comment: Please check my answer and give your feedback , does it solve your problem? or is this not the solution you want?

Comment: I am sorry I just checked your answer, So the frequency of exceptions has decreased after using your code but in a relatively low internet connectivity area it still crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `IndexPath` is correct by using `var numberOfSections: Int { get }` and `func numberOfItems(inSection section: Int) -> Int`

so you can do something like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

         self.collectionView?.reloadData()
         if self.collectionView?.numberOfSections > 0 {
             //you can decide which section to choose if you have more than one section but I am here using 0 for now...
             let numberOfItemsInSection = self.collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)

             if numberOfItemsInSection > 0 {
                 if let indexPath = IndexPath(item: numberOfItemsInSection - 1, section: 0) as? IndexPath {
                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
                 } 
             }
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is a race condition, you are doing `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` and immediately after it trying to scroll the `collectionView` to the bottom. It is possible that sometimes the Item is not ready yet and thats why you get an exception.

Also, it seems that you have some nested `async` calls. What you should do:

1. Move `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` out of the `dispatch`.
2. Check if the item for the `indexPath` that you are trying to scroll to, actually exists before doing `scrollToItem`.

Another approach could be that instead of scrolling inside you `Firebase` call, you checked whenever the last `Item` is created within the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and then executed the scroll action.

Comment: Can you please give me a code sample of how to check if the last item is created within the UICollectionViewDataSource ?